# How to graph, using ggplot2, a data frame with 3 independent discrete variables and a continuous dependent variable? (Other packages are welcome too)

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, 4d, ggtern

I have a data frame with 3 discrete and independent variables. These variables were combined with each other and the result of the combination generated a value for each set (continuous and numerical dependent variable). So far I have not been able to represent this result in a single plot.

I've already tried making surface plots, but this type of plot allows only 2 independent variables and one dependent variable. I also tried to make a ternary plot, but the axes of this type of graph are fixed and don't allow discrete variables.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas for doing this? I prefer plotting with the ggplot2 package, but other packages are also welcome.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)

Factor1 <- c('A', 'B')
Factor2 <- c('M', 'N', 'O')
Factor3 <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V3')

DF <- expand.grid(Factor1 = Factor1,
                  Factor2 = Factor2,
                  Factor3 = Factor3)

DF$Result <- runif(n =18,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 100)

# Surface plot
ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = Factor1,
           y = Factor2,
           fill = Result)) +
  geom_tile()

# Ternary plot (not run)
ggtern(data = DF,
       aes(x = Factor1,
           y = Factor2,
           z = Factor3)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Result))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

Factor1 <- c('A', 'B')
Factor2 <- c('M', 'N', 'O')
Factor3 <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V3')

DF <- expand.grid(Factor1 = Factor1,
                  Factor2 = Factor2,
                  Factor3 = Factor3)

DF$Result <- runif(n =18,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 100)

DF %>%
  unite(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3, col = "factor") %>%
  bind_cols(DF %>% select(-Result)) %>%
  arrange(Result) %>%
  {.x <- .; .x %>% mutate(factor = factor %>% factor(levels = .x$factor))} %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor, Result, color = Factor1, shape = Factor2)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```r
DF %>%
  arrange(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Factor1, Result, color = Factor2)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I liked this idea. Is there any way to arrange the points ascending? That is, the first point is the one with the smallest Result value and the last one with the largest Result value

Comment: I revised my answer